# ¿Como llenar una tabla en asp.net mvc4 con ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy realizando una consulta a una api con asp.net, la consulta la realizo bien y todo pero tengo un problema al llenar una tabla con ajax, no e podido visualizar los datos que me envía

aqui el codigo c#

```
public async Task<List<Sto_TraerCaracterizacionRespuestas>> Buscar(string contexto)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:53931/api/TraerCaracterizacionRespuestas?cod="+contexto+"&mod=nose");
        var lista = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sto_TraerCaracterizacionRespuestas>>(json);

        return lista;
    }
```

aqui el codigo de ajax

```
<script>
function buscar() {
    var valorEscogido = $("#Sto_TipoAlertas_Preguntas_TipoAlerta_Pregunta_CodigoPRegunta1").val();
    @**$.post('@Url.Action("Buscar")/?contexto=' + valorEscogido);*@        
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Buscar")", 
        data: "contexto=" + valorEscogido, 
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function (data) {
            $("#contenido").html('');
            if (data != null && $.isArray(data)) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>" + value.CodigoInterno1 + "</td><td>" + value.Respuesta + "</td><td>" + value.Detalles+"</td></tr>");
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

el html de la vista

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-md-10">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Sto_TipoAlertas_Preguntas.TipoAlerta_Pregunta.CodigoPRegunta1, Model.Sto_TipoAlertas_Preguntas.ListarComboBoxAPI, "Seleccionar una", new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
</div>
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>


<table class="table table-bordered" id="contenido">

   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>CodigoInterno</th>
          <th>Detalles</th>
          <th>Respuesta</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

pues souy nuevo con ajax y no se que estare haciendo mal

Comment: Puedes confirmar que si estas recibiendo datos desde el servidor?

Comment: si lo estoy recibiendo, pensé que era eso hasta que mostré eso en una vista por separado, y si lo estoy recibiendo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el html tabla.

Comment: listo ya agrege el html de la vista

Comment: podrías verificar la respuesta del ajax con las herramientas de desarrollado ya que me parece que el código esta bien( salvo por el hecho que limpias los encabezados de la tabla),  creo que no estas recibiendo un array o estas recibiendo null

Answer (score 1):

Estas limpiando el contenido de la tabla completo ya que id pertenece al `table` en si.

Intenta asignarle el `id="contenido"` al `tbody`, no a la tabla:

```js
var data = [{CodigoInterno1 : "3333", Respuesta : "Hola", Detalles :"Detalles detalles detalles"}, {CodigoInterno1 : "3333", Respuesta : "Hola", Detalles :"Detalles detalles detalles"}];

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    $("#contenido")
    .append("<tr><td>" + value.CodigoInterno1 + "</td><td>" + value.Respuesta + "</td><td>" + value.Detalles+"</td></tr>");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" >

   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>CodigoInterno</th>
          <th>Detalles</th>
          <th>Respuesta</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="contenido"></tbody>
</table>
```